# My comments are not being displayed in a django blog

Tags: python, django, django-comments

I am trying to add a comment section to add a comment section to my blog detail using django but when i run my server i get no error in the development server and the comments are not being displayed. I added the comments from my admin site.
The snippet of my code is below.

views.py

```
from .models import Post
from django.utils import timezone
from .forms import PostForm, CommentsForm
from  django.contrib.auth.decorators import user_passes_test
# Create your views here.


def home(request):
    return render (request, 'blogapp/home.html')

def blog_list(request):
    post = Post.objects.order_by('-published_date')
    context = {
        'posts':post
    }
    return render(request, 'blogapp/blog_list.html', context)

def blog_detail(request, pk=None):
    detail = Post.objects.get(pk=pk)
    context = {
        'detail': detail
    }
    return render(request, 'blogapp/blog_detail.html', context)


def add_post(request, pk=None):

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PostForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid:
            body = form.save(commit=False)
            body.published_date = timezone.now()
            body.save()
            return redirect('blog_list')
        form = PostForm()
    else:
        form = PostForm()

    context = {
        'form': form
    }
    return render(request, 'blogapp/add_post.html', context)

def add_comments(request, pk=None):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CommentsForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid:
            comment = form.save(commit=False)
            comment.date_added = timezone.now()
            comment.save()
            return redirect('blog_detail')
        form = CommentsForm()
    else:
        form = CommentsForm()

    context = {
        'form': form
    }
    return render(request, 'blogapp/add_comments.html', context)
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name="homepage"),
    path('blog/', views.blog_list, name="blog_list"),
    path('blog/post/<int:pk>/', views.blog_detail, name="blog_detail"),
    path('blog/add_post/', views.add_post, name="add_post"),
    path('blog/add_comments/', views.add_comments, name="add_comments"),
]
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Post, Comments

class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('author', 'title', 'post_description',  'image', 'image_description', 'body',)

class CommentsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comments
        fields = ('post', 'name', 'body',)
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

# Create your models here.


class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.user', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    body = models.TextField()
    post_description = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True, upload_to="image/")
    image_description = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, blank=True, null=True)

    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title



class Comments(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey('Post', related_name="comments", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body = models.TextField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s - %s' % (self.post.title, self.name)
```

blog_detail.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
    <article>
        <strong>
            <h1><b>{{ detail.title }}</b></h1>
        </strong>
        <h3>POST AUTHOR: {{ detail.author }}</h3>
        <h4><i>{{ detail.post_description }}</i></h4>
        <h4>PUBLISHED:{{ detail.published_date }}</h4>
        <p>
        <hr>
        {% if detail.image %}
            <center>
            <br>
                <img src="{{ detail.image.url }}" width="1000" height="700">
            <br><br>
                <i>IMAGE DESCRIPTION: {{ detail.image_description }}</i>
            </center>
        {% endif %}
        <hr>
        <br><br><br>
            {{ detail.body|linebreaksbr }}
        </p>
        <hr class="solid">
        <h2>COMMENTS ...</h2><a href="{% url 'add_comments' post.pk %}">Add One</a>
           {% for comment in post.comments.all %}
                <strong>
                    {{ comment.name }}-{{ comment.date_added }}
                </strong>
                    {{ comment.body }}
           {% endfor %}
    </article>
{% endblock %}
```

add_comments.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
    <article>
        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
            <h1>CREATE NEW BLOG POST.</h1>
            <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{ form.as_p }}
                <button type="submit">ADD COMMENT</button>
                <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{% url 'blog_detail' pk=post.pk %}"/>
            </form>
        {% else %}
            <h2>Login <a href="{% url 'login' %}">HERE</a> to add comments.</h2>
        {% endif %}
    </article>

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

in your template you use
`{% for comment in post.comments.all %}`
but in template context there is no `post` variable
you should use `{% for comment in detail.comments.all %}`